# CPLEX inserting results to Excel Sheet in main method

Tags: excel, program-entry-point, cplex, opl

I am creating a project where I have one model where one variable is always changing, namely ForecastMultiplier. I need to put the results of each iteration into an excel spreadsheet.
You can find main down below:

```
main { var source = new IloOplModelSource ("CS4.mod");
var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);

for (var k = 0.8; k <= 1.3; k += 0.1)
{ var modelInstance = new IloOplModel(def, cplex);
 var data = new IloOplDataSource("CS4.dat"); 
 modelInstance.addDataSource(data); 
 var data2= new IloOplDataElements(); 
data2.ForecastMultiplier=k;
  modelInstance.addDataSource(data2);
modelInstance.generate();
cplex.solve();
writeln("For The scenario:" + k +", Optimal solution: " + modelInstance.x);
modelInstance.end()
}
}
```

I had an idea to do it like this:

```
DataName to SheetWrite(ConnectionName, “Sheet!xx:xx”);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [technote](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-sheetwrite-when-range-unknown-until-runtime)

"The Excel range can be generated in ILOG Script and then be used by the SheetWrite instruction during postprocessing. "

[image]